# how to Bring pre-created custom field from docusign Sandbox to envelope using REST api?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have created some custom fields in my Docusign Sandbox, but I'm unable to bring them onto my envelope while sending it for eSignature.

I want Docusign custom fields to write back data to Salesforce fields when  signer has entered some value and signed the document

I have tried it with the below JSON. The envelope is created but I can't find the custom fields

```
{
 "emailBlurb": "String content",
 "emailSubject": "String content",
 "enableWetSign": "true",
 "recipientsLock": "false",
 "status": "sent",
 "customFields": {
  "listCustomFields": [{
   "name": "String content",
   "required": "false",
   "show": "true",
   "value": "String content",
   "listItems": [
    "String content"
   ]
  }],
  "textCustomFields": [{
   "name": "Insurance Expiration",
   "required": "false",
   "show": "true",
   "value": "012/02/2111"
  }]
 },
 "templateId": "152bacc1-9d5d-4243-9fe4-9dafe0785164",
 "templateRoles": [{
  "email": "r00ranjit@gmail.com",
  "name": "ranjit",
  "roleName": "CFO",
  "emailNotification": {
   "emailSubject": "String content",
   "emailBody": "String content"
  },
  "tabs": {
   "textTabs": [{
    "tabLabel": "String content111",
    "name": "String content1",
    "value": "String content"
   }]
  }
 }],

 "emailSettings": {
  "bccEmailAddresses": [{
   "email": "r00ranjit@gmail.co"
  }]
 },

"compositeTemplates": [{
    "inlineTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "customFields": {
            "textCustomFields": [{
                "name": "Insurance Expiration",
                "required": "true",
                "show": "true",
                "value": "06/06/2010"
            }]
        },
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
                "name": "Millard Fillmore",
                "email": "ranjit.r@attinadsoftware.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1"
            }]
        }
    }]
}]

}
```

Comment: I think you are the one that should provide code so it's easier to see the problem. Also, if you have some error logs that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

When you send from Salesforce, there is information passed to document (such as the SourceID and Source Object Type), that DocuSign Connect will attempt to match to a record to process a request to push the data back into Salesforce.

When you send from the API you need to provide this data in order for Salesforce to know where you want information published back.

[DocuSign API how to sync tags in template with Salesforce fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116843/docusign-api-how-to-sync-tags-in-template-with-salesforce-fields)

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92069/how-to-set-docusign-envelope-external-source-id-field-via-docusign-api

Those should help.